# What is the correct statement of the "Poisson limit theorem"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across a Wikipedia article entitled [Poisson limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) which states the following theorem:

> If $n\to\infty$ and $p\to0$ such that $np\to\lambda$, then
>   $$\binom n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\to e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$

This statement doesn't make any sense. Do they mean $p_n$ rather than $p$? If so, that doesn't gel with the example given below, in which we generate uniformly distributed random numbers between $0$ and $1$, so that there is a proability $p$ of them winding up in some interval. If we generate $n=100$ numbers, then we have $\lambda = np=100p$... so wait, $\lambda$ actually depends on $n$ rather than being a limit? And $p$ is constant? Then how can $np$ possible hope to converge? And how can a sequence indexed by $n$ converge to something that depends on $n$?

Either I'm seriously misunderstanding something or the article is badly written. Can anyone clarify for me what the theorem is meant to be?

Comment: For given $ \lambda$, if $p_n$ are such that $n p_n\to \lambda$ then $\binom n k p_n^k(1-p_n)^{n-k}\to \lambda^k \exp(-\lambda)/k!$.

Comment: @a... But in the example given underneath, $p$ would be fixed (or $p_n$ would be a constant sequence, if you prefer).

Comment: Consider the length of the big interval growing as $2n$. Then $p_n = 10/ (2n)$ and $np_n =5\to5$. The example is then just assuming that when $n=500$ we are close to the limit